# NestJS RedisIoAdapter is not assignable to parameter of type WebSocketAdapter<any, any, any>

Tags: javascript, typescript, redis, socket.io, nestjs

First of all, sorry for grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.

I just wanted to use Redis with NestJS and created an adapter for it. It would be more appropriate if I said I got the code from NestJS's own examples directly. Here is my Redis client:

```js
import Redis from "ioredis";
import { CONFIG } from "src/config";

export const redis = new Redis(CONFIG.REDIS_URL);
```

And this is the adapter:

```js
import { IoAdapter } from "@nestjs/platform-socket.io";
import { createAdapter } from "socket.io-redis";
import { redis } from "./redis";
import { ServerOptions } from "socket.io";

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
    createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
        const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
        const pubClient = redis;
        const subClient = redis.duplicate();
        const redisAdapter = createAdapter({
            pubClient,
            subClient,
        });
        server.adapter(redisAdapter);
        return server;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it on my application it says

```js
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app));
```

```
Argument of type 'RedisIoAdapter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebSocketAdapter<any, any, any>'. Type 'RedisIoAdapter' is missing the following properties from type 'WebSocketAdapter<any, any, any>': bindClientConnect, close
```

Thanks for all of your helps :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i have defined `RedisIoAdapter` class.

```js
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from 'socket.io-redis';
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';

const pubClient = new RedisClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT
});
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
const redisAdapter = createAdapter({ pubClient, subClient });

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    server.adapter(redisAdapter);
    return server;
  }
}
```

And in `main.ts` I have included following way:

```js
import { RedisIoAdapter } from './common/redis-adapter';

...
async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
   // Uses Redis Adapter
   app.useWebSocketAdapter(new 
   RedisIoAdapter((<any>app).getHttpServer()));
   ...
}

// Starting App now
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be because of not installing `@nestjs/websockets`.
Please make sure you have installed `@nestjs/websockets` npm package.

Comment: I'm sure I downloaded all the necessary packages completely.